# how to build apk Cannot run with sound null safety, because the following dependencies don't support null safety:

Tags: flutter, dart

Error: Cannot run with sound null safety, because the following dependencies
don't support null safety:

- package:intl

For solutions, see https://dart.dev/go/unsound-null-safety
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'D:\flutter_windows_3.7.7-stable\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1151
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'.

> Process 'command 'D:\flutter_windows_3.7.7-stable\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 21s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           22.8s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1

how to solve this error

Answer (score 0):

> One optimal solution is to utilize FVM (Flutter Version Management),
> an excellent tool for effectively managing various Flutter versions
> tailored to specific projects. It allows you to maintain different
> Flutter versions both locally for individual projects and globally,
> ensuring that your projects remain undisturbed after a Flutter
> upgrade.

Comment: just i solved the problem after update intl package